# Reading specified longitude/latitude

Tags: geolocation, hdfs, geocoding, geospatial, hdf

I am working on MERRA data in `Matlab`. I am interested in **plotting the data for specified co-ordinates** for MERRA300.prod.assim.tavg1_2d_rad_Nx product.

I need your help regarding how to extract specific location data (based on latitude/Longitude)?
I am attaching a code that I have worked on.
I have also seen examples on [here](http://hdfeos.org/zoo/GESDISC_MERRA_matlab.php) and [here](http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/forum/oceancolor/topic_show.pl?tid=3285).

```
file_name = 'MERRA300.prod.assim.tavg1_2d_rad_Nx.20150101.hdf';
GRID_NAME = 'EOSGRID'
file_id = hdfgd('open', file_name, 'rdonly');
grid_name='EOSGRID';
grid_id = hdfgd('attach', file_id, grid_name);
% datafield_name='U500';
datafield_name='ALBEDO';

[data, fail] = hdfgd('readfield', grid_id, datafield_name, [], [], []);
data=squeeze(double(data(:,:,1)));
data=data';

% size(data)

datafield_name='XDim';
[lon, status] = hdfgd('readfield', grid_id, datafield_name, [], [], []);
lon=double(lon);
datafield_name='YDim';
[lat, status] = hdfgd('readfield', grid_id, datafield_name, [], [], []);
lat=double(lat);
hdfgd('detach', grid_id);
hdfgd('close', file_id);
SD_id = hdfsd('start',file_name, 'rdonly');

% datafield_name='U500';
datafield_name='ALBEDO';

% size(lat)
% size(lon)
sds_index = hdfsd('nametoindex', SD_id, datafield_name);

sds_id = hdfsd('select',SD_id, sds_index);
fillvalue_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, '_FillValue');
[fillvalue, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, fillvalue_index);

missingvalue_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'missing_value');
[missingvalue, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, missingvalue_index);

long_name_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'long_name');
[long_name, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, long_name_index);

units_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'units');
[units, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, units_index);

scale_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'scale_factor');
[scale, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, scale_index);

scale = double(scale);
offset_index = hdfsd('findattr', sds_id, 'add_offset');
[offset, status] = hdfsd('readattr',sds_id, offset_index);

offset = double(offset);
hdfsd('endaccess', sds_id);
data(data==fillvalue) = NaN;
data(data==missingvalue) = NaN;
data = data*scale + offset ;
latlim = [floor(min(min(lat))),ceil(max(max(lat)))];
lonlim = [floor(min(min(lon))),ceil(max(max(lon)))];
min_data = floor(min(min(data)));
max_data = ceil(max(max(data)));

  % Find indexes for region along longitude.
 lon_region = (lon > 18.0 & lon < 45.0);
 i = find(lon_region,1,'first');
 j = find(lon_region,1,'last');

 % Subset data using the above indices.
 % lat = lat(i:j);
 % lon = lon(i:j);
 % time = time(i:j);
 % data = data(:,i:j);

 % Find indexes region along latitude.
 lat_region = (lat > 18.0 & lat < 45.0);
 i = find(lat_region,1,'first');
 j = find(lat_region,1,'last');

 % Subset data using the above indices.
 lat = lat(i:j);
 lon = lon(i:j);
 % time = time(i:j);
 % data = data(:,i:j);


f = figure('Name', file_name,'visible','on');

axesm('MapProjection','eqdcylin','Frame','on','Grid','on', ...
      'MapLatLimit',latlim,'MapLonLimit',lonlim, ...
      'MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on')
coast = load('coast.mat');

% surfacem(lat,lon,data);
surfm(lat,lon,data);
colormap('Jet');
caxis([min_data max_data]); 

% Change the value if you want to have more than 10 tick marks.
ntickmarks = 10;
granule = floor((max_data - min_data) / ntickmarks);

h=colorbar('YTick', min_data:granule:max_data);

plotm(coast.lat,coast.long,'k')

title({file_name; ...
       [long_name  [' at TIME=0']]}, ...
       'Interpreter', 'None', 'FontSize', 16,'FontWeight','bold');

set (get(h, 'title'), 'string', units, 'FontSize', 16,'FontWeight','bold');

% Use the following if your screen isn't too big (> 1024 x 768). 
scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');

% The following fixed-size screen size will look better in PNG if
% your screen is too large.
scrsz = [1 1 800 600];
set(f,'position',scrsz,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I don't see the code you have worked on so far. Could you update your question and paste the code? This would greatly help us to see what your are doing and what you might be missing to extract the geolocation.

Comment: so sorry. i am new to stackoverflow and i was unable to attach txt file

Comment: No problem, but you do not need to attach a `.txt` file, simply paste the code in your question, look here for an explanation how to post and format code using the SO editor: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting .

Comment: any one there,with a solution?